# Converting a Model to PolyModel in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What are the consequences if you switch a model's base class from db.Model to db.PolyModel (You decide you want to add polymorphism) after it already has entities stored in the datastore?

Also, is there any reason not to *always* create your models as PolyModels, so subclassing is never an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for you for your first question, it doesn't seem like an issue, since [changing modal base class is a documented way to remove properties](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema.html) by Google.

I believe that PolyModel has some hidden cost when accessing the properties, this is why you should start with Model and switch only if necessary.

Comment: thanks for that link- makes sense. Do you any more info on hidden costs of PolyModel?

Comment: Polymodel stores some of the data in hidden property list that increases number of required indexes exponentially if you have custom index that refers list properties in your model.

Comment: Teemu- thanks- I've made this it's own question, if you care to answer/ get some credit ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186751/cost-of-polymodel-over-model-in-google-app-engine

Comment: Just because you can change from `db.Model` to `db.Expando` doesn't mean you can change to `db.PolyModel` without problems. It happens that you can, though.

Comment: @NickJohnson I know that directly its doesn't mean that, but since the documentation is lacking on this subject (hint, hint) one can only assume.